How to solve "cannot use 'paired' in formula method" in t.test() in R
I am running a code to do t.test() in R, like below, but got error:
library(datasets)
beaver2

t.test(
  temp~activ, 
  data=beaver2, 
  alternative=c("two.sided"), 
  mu=0, 
  paired=FALSE
)


Error in t.test.formula(temp ~ activ, data = beaver2, alternative = c("two.sided"), : cannot use 'paired' in formula method
Traceback:

t.test(temp ~ activ, data = beaver2, alternative = c("two.sided"),
.     mu = 0, paired = FALSE)
t.test.formula(temp ~ activ, data = beaver2, alternative = c("two.sided"),
.     mu = 0, paired = FALSE)
stop("cannot use 'paired' in formula method")

I checked the help document of t.test(), the paired has a default value as FALSE. If I remove paired argument, it works. Does anyone can help me with that? I would like to assign paired = TRUE

for the formula method, you have to use Pair (and make sure your data is in the proper format), there are examples in ?t.test and ?wilcox.test this was somewhat recently changed and throws an error to be safe since you should be properly merging by ID rather than rely on x ~ y to do the reshaping under the hood
